# How to reset the id number of newly generated PostGIS topology?

Tags: postgis, topology

I'm trying to create a clean, new topology for testing by discarding the old topology first, i.e.:

```
SELECT DropTopology('ch13_topology');

SELECT CreateTopology('ch13_topology', 32610, 0.05);
```

However, one issue I have is that `topology.CreateTopology` is giving a different (increasing) id number each time for the topology. The first time, it returns `1`, the second time it returns `2`, and so on, even though the old topology has been dropped.

I understand it's safe to always increase the id number. But,

*Is there a way to make `topology.CreateTopology` return the smallest id number possible*?

In the case shown above, this would be *always* `1`, or whatever number it is at the first call of {drop,create}topology(). I need this so that I don't have to change the id numbers in subsequent SQL statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The topology id is provided by PostgreSQL's [sequence generator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html). You can modify this generator's next value with [`setval`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html). For example, if you want the generator's next value to be 1, then:

```
SELECT setval('topology.topology_id_seq', 1, false);
```